# Probability that sample path ends at a high.

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am trying to get the probability that a sample path ends at a high. To formulate the problem,

let sequence $\{S_n\}$ be a random walk, with $S_0 = 0$, defined by
$$ S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$$ 
Where $\{X_n\}$ are iid random variables with $P(X=1)=p$, $P(X=-1)=1-p$

Also define $M_n=max\{S_1, S_2,...,S_n\}$.

What is $$\sum_{x=0}^n P(M_n = x, S_n = x),\ where\ n\ is\ a\ even\ number$$ Simply put, the ending value of the sample path has to be greater than or equal to all the values that came before.

The hint was to think recursively, starting from $P(M_2=x, S_2=x)$ and generalize, but I counldn't quite get it.

Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is another hint: (1) If we end on the highest, either we just came from the highest-seen-so-far (and we created a new highest by increasing), or we just came from the second-highest-seen-so-far (and we went up to the existing highest). (2) In the latter case, there must have been some time where we reached the highest point $x$, and the Markov chain during the remaining time is equivalent to starting fresh and ending on a "highest of zero."